# Problems with big fixed-width flat files

Tags: java, stack-overflow, flat-file, fixed-width

I'm trying to read a fixed-width flat file with *JRecordBind*. Each line can be a subrecord of the previous one and the first line and the last one are header and footer of root record.

**Example:**

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx -> Record1 header with list of Records2
yyyyyyyyyyy1h -> Record2 instance 1header with list of Records3
@@@@@@@@@@@@1 -> Record3 instance1
@@@@@@@@@@@@2 -> Record3 instance2
yyyyyyyyyyy1f -> Record2 footer
yyyyyyyyyyy2h
@@@@@@@@@@@@3
@@@@@@@@@@@@4
yyyyyyyyyyy2f
zzzzzzz
```

My problem is the size of the file with many records (in my case 140,000), a StackOverFlow exception is thrown.

I'm analyzing *BeanIO* as an alternative to *JRecordBind*.

What is the best option with these kind of files?

Comment: I would read the lines to a LIst<String> with commons IO and write a function to parse each line.

Comment: What ever library you use, I would suggest processing one record at a time; that will scale much better. 140,000 is not a big file.